# What is tclsh's equivalent of bash's -c (run command)?

Tags: tclsh

I need something similar:

```
$ tclsh --run-command puts hello
```

to print out: `hello`.

Like `-c` in `bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest is to create a TCL script: `runner.tcl` with the following content:

```
#runner.tcl

eval $argv
```

Use:

```
$ tclsh runner.tcl puts hello
```